# How to show NZ$ / AU$ instead of just $ using this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the below code as part of a toggle switch solution for my site and it's great but it only shows up a dollar sign for each currency as they're both in dollars.
What would I add to have it say NZ$ and AU$ instead of the naked $?

```
<span data-currency="AUD" class="left">&dollar;</span>
<span data-currency="NZD" class="right">&dollar;</span>
```

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: You might wanna show us that code you talked about.

Comment: I keep putting it in but it just turns it into dollar signs. ie actually using the code - how can i show the code without it using it?

Comment: Well, you just type `NZ` and `AU` on your keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
<span data-currency="AUD" class="left">AU&dollar;</span>
<span data-currency="NZD" class="right">NZ&dollar;</span>
```

Which should result in:

AU$

NZ$

Is that what you're trying to get?
Anything inside the `<span></span>` should show up for your users.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you, I thought it had to come after the &. Sorry - total noob. Thanks!

Comment: @Rhonnie so why did not you simply try it? You'll never learn anything if you don't try and research yourself.